# Partial redrawing bitmaps in Android

Tags: android

I am coding a snake game in Android, and I am blocked by the fact that i can't draw a wall using a loop inside `onDraw` method, the wall just don't show up.

Is there a way i can draw the wall so that the `onDraw` will keep it intact and keep on redrawing others things (snake and objects) ?

GameView:

```
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {


                gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);

                gameLoopThread.start();


            }
@Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        if(drawWall) {

            int i = 0;
            while(i < getWidth()) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(wall.getImage(), i, 0, null);
                i += 17;


            }


            drawWall = false;


        }


        x += dx;
        y += dy;

}
```

GameLoop:

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread {

private GameView view;

private boolean running = false;



public GameLoopThread(GameView view) {

    this.view = view;

}



public void setRunning(boolean run) {

    running = run;

}



@Override

public void run() {

    while (running) {

        Canvas c = null;

        try {

            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();

            synchronized (view.getHolder()) {
                view.onDraw(c);


            }

        } finally {

            if (c != null) {

                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);

            }

        }

      }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your view hierarchy is, however, why not make your life easier and just have an `ImageView` behind your SurfaceView with your walls on it? Or have a `FrameLayout` contain your `SurfaceView` and have the walls as a background image for the `FrameLayout`?The collision with the walls is going to be handled in the code and the graphical representation of the walls is really just for the users benefit.

Put the images of the walls in the background and let Android worry about it, in your `SurfaceView` just concentrate of redrawing the snake and the dots.

That being said, looks like you're drawing in a background thread. You can't actually do that on Android and you should be drawing in the main thread.